# UK visa refusal - reapply with SU07/12?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

I am am UK national ( Old British born and  bred )  , currently resident in a Gulf country .

I invited a Bangladeshi  man , a car mechanic known to me  for 6 years and also resident in the same Gulf country   ,  to visit me in the UK for a 1 week holiday  .
I said that my own house in London  would be his contact  point and that I would cover any unexpected cost .  He would pay for his own travel to and within the UK.

The application visa was refused – see attached.

If he applied again  , but this time with a  Sponsorship Undertaking  SU07/12  given  by  person in the UK  , is it likely that the visa would be granted .

Note - if I were resident in the UK I would  give such an undertaking .

[image: Refusal letter part1]

[image: Refusal letter part2]

Comment: Welcome to TSE! This is a very standard type of refusal notice a+c+e. They like to use those grounds a lot and we have a canonical article less than a year old to explain about it. And no, using the SU forms will not help.  Please read the linked article, many thanks.